# Python Codecs module register error infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I download a file that may contain chinese characters and I want to convert it to utf8.

In some case, there are characters that cannot be converted and I replace the character that cannot be converted by a question mark '�'.

I created a program that receive 2 parameters , one is file path , other one is source file encoding

In some cases, this code end in an infinite loop and I have no idea why.
What is causing this infinite loop ?

Source Code:

```
class ErrorHandler:
    def __init__(self,file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.previous_end_position = -65535
        self.error_threshold = 0
    def error_handler(self,exception):
        if exception.start == self.previous_end_position+1:
            self.error_threshold+=1
        if self.error_threshold >= 64:
            raise exception
        else:
            print("Start:"+str(exception.start))
            print("End:"+str(exception.end))
            self.previous_end_position = exception.end
        return ("�",-1,)

src_path = sys.argv[1]
try:
    src_ext = src_path[src_path.rindex("."):]
    dest_path = src_path[:src_path.rindex(".")]+"_utf8"+src_ext
except:
    dest_path = src_path+"_utf8"

src_encoding = sys.argv[2]

codecs.register_error("myreplace",ErrorHandler(src_path).error_handler)

with io.TextIOWrapper(open(src_path,"rb"),encoding=src_encoding,errors="myreplace") as src , open(dest_path,"w") as dest:
    for line in src:
        dest.write(line)
```

Comment: You can set the codec to do it automatically using the "error handling" parameter.

Comment: I don't like use default 'replace' handler .
Since i need additional process while fail to convert source byte
BTW , FYI if i using default 'replace' handler it work perfectly .

Comment: I suggest using `pdb` or other python debugger and placing a breakpoint inside your ErrorHandler so you can inspect the context while going line by line in order to figure out what is wrong.